# Angular 2 project filestructure

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, frontend

If I am creating an Angular 2 application from scratch, is interoperability of modules, components, directives, ect. affected by folder structure if the filepaths of the 'imports' are adjusted accordingly (assuming only files containing these things are the only thing we're shuffling). For example, I decide to have folders such as 'components', 'services', 'styles', 'main' (for root module+component), as opposed to having all of the mentioned thigs in one folder...I could divide those things any which way I wanted as long as 'import {'@blahblah'}' reflected relative position in directory appropriately?

Comment: The [tag:angularjs] tag is for angular 1.x only, for Angular 2+ use tag: [tag:angular]

Answer (score 2):

First, if you are creating a new Angular application from scratch, I'd highly recommend using the Angular CLI: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli. If you do, it has its own thoughts on the project file structure.

Second, if you put the templates and styles in the *same* folder as the associated component, you can simplify your code and use relative paths.

Other than that ... you are free to set up your file structure anyway you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you should not. Dividing project files by type instead of feature is considered as bad practice, see https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-04-07

Answer (score 1):

As it being already stated here you can use [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to start your project having all best practices in place and to check out [Angular styleguide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide) that give you some more details/theory on that.

However it is also very important to get your project logical structure right for that you can check this [repo](https://github.com/kuncevic/angular-modular-project-structure) as example (FYI it is build with [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)) and that [ng-conf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o) talk by @DeborahK also checkout this [article](https://medium.com/@ct7/angular2-module-architecture-and-example-seed-project-35b7410264f5) on the same matter.